# Is it possible, when i save a data in postgresql table, automatically, id of record save in another table without trigger

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables. First table is called Person. Second table is called PersonRule. Person table has much columns. But PersonRule has just 2 columns. In the person table, there is a column called ruleid. The column at the same time, there is in the PersonRule table. Is it possible, when i insert to data Person table, i want to automatically create a record in PersonRule table without trigger.?

And in PostgreSQL how can i do this.?

Comment: No. To me it looks like there is a Foreign Key relation from Person -> PersonRule on ruleid, assuming ruleid is unique in PersonRule. Is that the case, if so then the PersonRule would need to exist first. In any case you will need to either do two queries or use a trigger. A better answer awaits more complete information 1) Actual tables structure. 2) Example data.

Comment: I mean this is a perfect example for a trigger use case. What is the reason you don't want to use a trigger? I don't think there is another solution and I don't see why there should be another. Triggers are fast and pretty easy to use.